# How to avoid __builtin___memset_chk warning?

Tags: c++, gcc

I am running gcc 4.8.4 and compiling with options:

```
CXXFLAGS+= -Wall -std=c++11 -pedantic -lpthread
```

I want to zero a structure using memset:

```
typedef struct
{
    TSfMsgHeader    errorHeader;
    TErrorHeader    errorType;
    TErrorDetails   errorDetails;
}TErrorInd;

uint8 g_errorIndBlock[16];

TErrorInd* p_msg = (TErrorInd *)&g_errorIndBlock[0];
memset((int*)p_msg, 0, sizeof(TErrorInd));
```

This results in warning:

> In function ‘void* memset(void*, int, size_t)’,
>       inlined from ‘void sendMsgPduError(TMsgPduError*, uint32)’ at ../MessageHandling.cpp:174:46:
>
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string3.h:84:70: warning: call to void* __builtin___memset_chk(void*, int, long unsigned int, long unsigned int) will always overflow destination buffer [enabled by default]
>
> return __builtin___memset_chk (__dest, __ch, __len, __bos0 (__dest));

I realise that this is a sensible warning but I don't know how to modify the code to fix it.

I read that std::fill_n is preferred to memset. Is that correct?

If so, how would I replace memset by fill_n?

Comment: Besides, why do you need to cast into `int*`?

Comment: `g_errorIndBlock[16];` why 16? how do you know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the value of sizeof(TErrorInd), for some reason gcc thinks that it is greater than sizeof(uint8) * 16. Maybe you did not counted alignment bytes, computing the struct size.

Answer (score 2):

`-std=c++11` is a rather unusual flag for what's really C89 code. But I digress.

The proper fix is just

```
TErrorInd p_msg { 0 };
```

No `char[]` (improper alignment), no `memset` (not needed as it's already zeroed)

Comment: In the original post there's no `TErrorInd` data. `p_msg` is `TErrorInd*`.